# What is the best approach to check transaction status?

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric

The Invoke API is accepting the transaction and returning a transaction code and ok status straightaway.

The request is processed afterward and can actually be rejected by the chaincode or the ledger addition can fail for any reason.

What is the best approach to check if the transaction is successfully processed by the chaincode and the result added to the ledger?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fabric v0.6 invoke is an asynchronous process and the only way to get any indication of a success or a failure is with the help of the built-in event framework. [Section 3.5 of Fabric Protocol Specification contains Event related information](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/master/docs/protocol-spec.md)
This event framework generates 3 kind of events.

1. Block events
2. Rejection events
3. Chaincode events

If you are interested in detecting a successful chaincode execution, then you should track for **Block events**. You just have to monitor for the occurance of a Block Event Message containing the UUID you received when you submitted the Invoke transaction.
If you want to keep track of the Chaincode failures, then you should track **Rejection events** also. Again, track the Message containing your UUID as TxId.
Please note that incase of a Rejection event, a block event would not be created. And vice versa.
Fabric examples have a sample implementation which can be used to give an idea on how to write code. https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/tree/master/examples/events/block-listener

*Please note that from Hyperledger Fabric v1.x.x onwards, the architecture is entirely different. Above answer was given to a question asked in the context of Hyperledger Fabric v0.6*